# Diffences between map start and aliases

Tags: configuration, dojo, aliases

I'm using dojo 1.11.2 to build a web application. I noticed a different behaviour between the usage of **map star** (*) and **aliases**.

I want to override all focus module with my custom version.

Please see the following examples. [In my application I also use gridx component]

***Using star map***

```
map: {
       "*": {
              'dijit/focus': 'custom/myFocus'
            }
     }
```

In this case my modules uses myFocus component. Gridx modules continue to use the dijit focus module.

***Using aliases***

```
aliases: [
           'dijit/focus': 'custom/myFocus'
         ]
```

In this case my modules and gridx modules use myFocus component.

Probably I'm making a mistake in the usage of map star and aliases, but reading the documentation I thought that are equal.

What is the problem?

Comment: According to this [article](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/07/03/dojo-faq-what-is-the-map-config-option/) aliases create global shortcuts and map with '*' applies to all modules. Propably your gridx modules are outside mapped scope or there may be some check to avoid replacing modules in libraries.

Comment: What do you mean with "outside mapped scope"?

Comment: I mean that propably mapping could be applied to all modules in some directory and gridx could be placed in your project outside that directory.

Comment: Ok @barbsan, Thank you!